# Regex - Find all the digits that occur to a certain character

Tags: java, regex

I would like to ask you about regex expression - I need to get all numbers that occur to a certain character. For example:

```
"$z4~min.~00~s" -> 4
"$z12~min.~00~s" -> 12
```

I simply need first number in the string, I don't need numbers after dot in the string.

I am using Java for this project.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: You may use `^\D*(\d+)`. The number will be in group #1.

Comment: You can use capturing goups to get the regex values that you want, using () enclosing the values that matters to you. There is a very useful site to help you writing regex, http://www.regex101.com

Comment: @41686d6564 This works, but it takes dollar and "z" character aswell :/

Comment: @PetrJelínek As I said above, you need to get the value of the first group, not the value of the entire match. For example: `matcher.group(1)`. Alternatively, you may use `(?<=^\D{2})\d+` if the number is always preceded by exactly two characters. Or `(?<=^\D{2,x})\d+` where `x` is the maximum number of characters that might come before the number.

Comment: Ok, but how should I do that? I have this regex - (\d+)

Comment: Number could be 1 - x long, so it would be good to use + sign (one or more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^\\D*(\\d+)");
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("$z12~min.~00~s");
if (matcher.find()) {
    String firstNumber = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(firstNumber);
}
```